# Copy content from webpage - and paste content + link

Tags: html, css

[Sports Illustrated cnn link](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/basketball/ncaa/men/gameflash/2010/12/07/64366_recap.html)

Copy some content on the above web page and paste it in a notepad, you will see in addition to what copied there is a also a Read more link of the web page you copied from.

How did they do this? Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses JavaScript provided by **[Tynt](http://www.tynt.com)**.

It basically uses Javascript's `onCopy` event handler.

Information about onCopy:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.oncopy
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536916(VS.85).aspx

Analysis of how Tynt works:

- http://blog.nparashuram.com/2009/03/how-tynt-works-technical-details.html